# Authenticate Javascript based Web client

Tags: javascript, authentication, web-client

We have developed multi-client application i.e. the business logic resides on server side and the interfaces are exposed via REST API and mobile/web-client consumes the APIs.

The application allows different users to signup/login to get user specific data. We use http digest based authentication and a token mechanism to keep track of user state.

However, we want to restrict the access of APIs i.e. only our registered mobile/web-client could access them. So we introduced a second layer of authentication and named it service layer authentication. We are using our custom token based system just like we did for user authentication. The over all flow for mobile clients is good enough for us but for web-clients we have issues. If we embed the user credentials in Javascript, anyone can extract those credentials and consume the APIs.

In summary, all we want is to identify/authenticate the Javscript based web-client upon ajax calls.

P.S. Just for clarification, with web-client I mean our web application not the browser.

Comment: you should only serve the sensitive js to authenticated clients. that way, not everyone can extract them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a credential exchange, where the user provides hard credentials once (such as username and password) and then recieves a scoped token which is used as an authentication mechanism on subsequent requests.

Disclaimer: I work at Stormpath, we offer user management as a service.

If you are building a Single-Page-App (i.e. AngularJS) I would recommend my recent writing on the subject:  https://stormpath.com/blog/why-we-rebuilt-with-angular/

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I've seen one of your presentation on youtube and you guys are good.

On the current issue, we are satisfied with User Authentication process but we also want to authenticate the Web-Client. By any means can we authenticate the Javascript based client while using REST APIs?